# Como resolver mensagem Illegal offset type

Tags: php

Estou recebendo essa mensagem de erro:

> PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type in E:\home\topdeia\Web\n-chipi\atualizar-dados.php on line 9

O código que tenho é esse:

```
session_start();

$acao = $_POST['acao'];

if ( isset($acao) && $acao == 'atualizar-quantidade' ){
    $id = isset($_POST["id_qtd"]) ? $_POST["id_qtd"] : null;
    $_SESSION["quantidade"][$id] = $_POST['quantidade'];        
}
```

Seguindo uma dica, fiz isso, acrescentei `(string)`

```
session_start();

$acao = $_POST['acao'];

if ( isset($acao) && $acao == 'atualizar-quantidade' ){
    $id = isset($_POST["id_qtd"]) ? $_POST["id_qtd"] : null;
    **$_SESSION["quantidade"][$id] = (string)$_POST['quantidade'];**        
}
```

A mensagem persiste.

Comment: Qual é a linha  `9` nesse trecho ? Olha que você atribui de forma condicional `null` à variável `$id` e depois usa ela como índice.

Comment: Olá @Edilson, a linha 9 é a que está marcada com asteriscos no segundo trecho de código.

Comment: O lógico não seria, se não existir `id_qntd` não prosseguir com a mudança ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tudo indica que a variável `$id` não é um índice valido para o array `$_SESSION["quantidade"]`.

Faça assim para só executar essa linha caso seja um índice válido.

```
session_start();

$acao = $_POST['acao'];

if ( isset($acao) && $acao == 'atualizar-quantidade' ){
    $id = isset($_POST["id_qtd"]) ? $_POST["id_qtd"] : null;
    if (isset($_SESSION["quantidade"][$id])) {
        $_SESSION["quantidade"][$id] = (string)$_POST['quantidade'];        
    }
}
```